# CakePHP 2.4.9: using data from two databases from controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.4

I have two databases with identical tables (one for regular use, one for update purposes). I  I want to be able to access data from both of them. This is the code I'm using:

```
$this->Channel->useDbConfig = 'default';
debug($this->Channel->find('count')); // Output: 641939, correct!
$this->Channel->useDbConfig = 'update';
debug($this->Channel->find('count')); // Output: 641939, wrong, should be 641938
```

The second useDbConfig isn't working. It's still manipulating data from the default datasource instead of the update datasource. I guess this has something to do with the default datasource being used right before it. But how can I access the update database **immediately** after using the default one?

Comment: If you are using 2.1 or later try Model::setDataSource() as this will set the schemaName too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Corie. No such luck. If I replace useDbConfig with setDataSource, I get the same result. Only if I remove the first two lines do I get the result from the update-database.

Comment: Calling `$this->Channel->setDataSource('update');` would definitely switch the source regardless of the preceding statements.

Comment: Are you really using 2.3? And if so, which version exactly?

Comment: @ADmad: thanks for your comment. I tried this, it really doesn't work.
ndm: I'm sorry, I forgot I had upgraded to 2.4.9 already.

I found that this piece of code works with the new datasource, though:

`$channel1 = $this->Channel->query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM channels", false);`

It looks like a cacheQueries-problem, but if it is, I'm wondering how I can disable cacheQueries in regular model methods.

Comment: Is this going through an association?
It could be the counter cache.

I went through the Model methods and you should definitely use `$this->Channel->setDataSource('update');` and also check if `$this->Channel->cacheQueries` is `false`.

Reading through the model I found that setting `Channel->useDbConfig` or calling `Channel->setDataSource()` do the same thing, but one should always use the function for clarity.